# Adwhirl causes my Android app to crash?

Tags: android, crash, adwhirl

i have a very simple setup for my app in order to test adwhirl

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout;

public class testads extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testads);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
        AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = new AdWhirlLayout(this, "my_ADWHIRLSDKCODE");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adWhirlLayoutParams =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.addView(adWhirlLayout, adWhirlLayoutParams);
        layout.invalidate();
    }
}
```

and the layout file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/layout_main"
  >
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <AdWhirlLayout android:id="@+id/adwhirl_layout"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When i run it, the app crashes... This should be so simple, what am i doing wrong?

edit: i am sorry i did not include the log error before... here it is

```
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vicvic.android/com.vicvic.android.testads}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class AdWhirlLayout
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class AdWhirlLayout
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at com.vicvic.android.testads.onCreate(testads.java:18)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     ... 11 more
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.AdWhirlLayout in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.vicvic.android-2.apk]
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
04-11 17:21:36.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2084):     ... 20 more
04-11 17:21:36.375: WARN/ActivityManager(66):   Force finishing activity com.vicvic.android/.testads
04-11 17:21:36.895: WARN/ActivityManager(66): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44f65b98 com.vicvic.android/.testads}
04-11 17:21:42.635: DEBUG/dalvikvm(185): GC_EXPLICIT freed 149 objects / 10872 bytes in 86ms
04-11 17:21:47.308: WARN/ActivityManager(66): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44f65b98 com.vicvic.android/.testads}
04-11 17:21:47.735: DEBUG/dalvikvm(267): GC_EXPLICIT freed 31 objects / 1400 bytes in 178ms
04-11 17:22:29.135: DEBUG/SntpClient(66): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an error message it's just guessing.
Try something like 
`<com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout>` in your XML using the package name of the AdWhirlLayout-Class

Comment: makes sense, i attached the logcat

Answer (score 1):

Without the error from your logcat we can only guess:

You have defined `AdWhirlLayout` in your xml but you create a new one in your `onCreate`. I guess you should also use findViewById for your adwhirllayout and you shouldn't add it to your layout_main, because it is already there.

Thats just a guess because you didn't provide an error message...

**edit**: You should decide: Do you layout in xml (than follow what @Hache has said) or do it in onCreate. Don't try to mix both ways, especially not adding the same view twice (once in xml, once in onCreate)

Comment: makes sense, i attached the logcat

Comment: I updated my answer. Try adding the view in your xml file only and just use findViewById() in onCreate()